# Lexical - Underline TextNode based on cursor position

Tags: javascript, typescript, editor, lexical

I want to achieve a following functionality:

[image: lexical playground example with one of the words being underlined]

(notice that "are" is underlined while other words are normal). The cursor position decides what TextNode should be underlined.

I tried to use `editor.registerNodeTransform` to split single TextNode into multiple TextNodes (splitting by space " " character) and `editor.registerCommand(SELECTION_CHANGE_COMMAND)` to style it as underlined but i'm having issues with lexical infinitely updating itself.

Here is a gist:

```
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { TextNode } from "lexical";
import {
  $getSelection,
  SELECTION_CHANGE_COMMAND,
  COMMAND_PRIORITY_NORMAL
} from "lexical";

export default function UnderlinePlugin() {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    editor.registerNodeTransform(TextNode, (textNode) => {
      const textContent = textNode.getTextContent();

      const whiteSpaceIndices = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < textContent.length; i++) {
        if (textContent[i] === " ") {
          whiteSpaceIndices.push(i);
          whiteSpaceIndices.push(i + 1);
        }
      }

      editor.update(() => {
        textNode.splitText(...whiteSpaceIndices);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return editor.registerCommand(
      SELECTION_CHANGE_COMMAND,
      () => {
        const selection = $getSelection();

        const [node] = selection.getNodes();

        // node.setFormat("underline"); // <- causes lexical to indefinitely update
      },
      COMMAND_PRIORITY_NORMAL
    );
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-boyd-p5nr7n?file=/src/plugins/UnderlinePlugin.js:277-292)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please clarify what it is you're trying to achieve exactly? Are you wanting words to automatically be underlined based on cursor position? Do you want the word to be underline by clicking on the word?

Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I want the words to be automatically underlined based on cursor position.

> Do you want the word to be underlined by clicking on the word?
Well, I guess clicking on the word places the cursor somewhere in-between the word, so yes, the word should be underlined in this case.

When there is a single character word I would assume that it should be underlined when the cursor is placed _after_ the character.

Comment: I'm assuming you've read the documentation on `nodeTransforms` & avoiding infinite loops? https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/transforms